# How to execute shell script during start of the machine in AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ec2-ami

I have create EC2 instance(name: firstinstance) and install my application on it.
Then I have created AMI image using the above instance
Then I have created EC2 instance(name: secondinstance) from AMI image

But now I want to update the yml configuration file in EC2(secondinstance). I don't want to do it during creation of secondinstance using userdata. My AMI image automatically run the provided script after creation of EC2 instance using that Image. How can I do it?

I have tried setting the following in User data of firstinstance. It doesn't get created in secondinstance

```
touch /tmp/testfile.txt
```

Whenever anyone create the EC2 instance using AMI image, that instance should run the provided script after creation of that instance

Comment: What's wrong with using UserData on the `secondinstance`?

Comment: @Marcin Many users will use my AMI image like secondinstance. User shouldn't do that. AMI image should take care of script to run post creation of EC2 instance

Comment: I see. Then you have to make custom solution for that. There are may ways allowing you to run scripts on first boot only, e.g. [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/853396/run-script-on-first-boot). So before you make your AMI, you set it up witch such script. Then any new instance from the AMI will run the script only once.